# 'My' is not a member of 'Global' designer error in Visual Studio Community (2015)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, dataset, windows-forms-designer

I've had an issue lately that I cannot figure out.

When I make changes to any dataset query in Visual Studio I immediately get a bunch of **'My' is not a member of 'Global'** errors residing in the dataset designer.

This is one example of where the error is shown:

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Private Sub InitConnection()
        Me._connection = New Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
        Me._connection.ConnectionString = Global.My.MySettings.Default.PRODDBConnectionString
    End Sub
```

Being that the designer is an automatically created file, I really have no idea what has changed.

This can be fixed by replacing all instances of Global. with nothing, but I'd have to do this every single time I make a change which isn't practical at all.

I'm not sure what I might have changed in the project/solution for everything to now be labeled 'Global', but I'd sure love to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this by clearing out the Root namespace in the project properties.

Comment: Do the changes persist in the designer or do I have to worry about it being re-generated?